# VGroup - how to apply distributed layout

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I place 3 BorderContainer on a VGroup.
Each container has different size.
Can you explain to me how to distribute inside the VGroup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your three BorderContainers to take up an equal amount of your VGroup, try something like the following.

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="33%">
        ...
    </s:BorderContainer>
    <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="33%">
        ...
    </s:BorderContainer>
    <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="33%">
        ...
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:VGroup>
```

Or, if you're declaring them in Actionscript.

```
var b:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
...
b.percentWidth = 100;
b.percentHeight = 33;
```

etc.

Comment: It's not possible because, 3 border container have different height. I need space between 3 is the same, but I can't decide that each is 33% height. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below code may give some idea to implement:-
You can modify your logic as per requirement as you can get dynamic height for your container.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var heightArray:Array = new Array(200,800,400);
//dynamic array created at run time
            private function calculateHeight():void
            {
                var totalHeight:Number = heightArray[0]+heightArray[1]+heightArray[2];
                //for more values in array use for loop as per user specification
                container1.percentHeight = (heightArray[0]/totalHeight) * 100;
                container2.percentHeight = (heightArray[1]/totalHeight) * 100;
                container3.percentHeight = (heightArray[2]/totalHeight) * 100;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete="calculateHeight()">
        <s:BorderContainer id="container1" width="100%" >
        </s:BorderContainer>
        <s:BorderContainer  id="container2" width="100%" >
        </s:BorderContainer>
        <s:BorderContainer  id="container3" width="100%" >
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```